# discord.py How to make a bot that private/direct messages multiple people at once?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot that proctors a game that involves pm'ing players secret messages. However, I only know how to make the bot pm one person at a time. Example:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def poke(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await bot.send_message(user, 'boop')
```

Is there a way for me to store "user" in, say, a string? Perhaps make a for loop and have it send a message to player[0], then player[1], etc...?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead have an argument list `*users`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def poke(ctx, *users: discord.User):
    for user in users:
        await bot.send_message(user, 'boop')
```

Then you can just `!poke @User1 @User2 ...`